# Where is the 1$

Tags: logical-deduction

The owner of a ration store sells sugar sacks weighing 50Kg for \$50, but he gives a special discount to his neighbors, and sells it to them for \$45.

One day the owner, whose name is Jack, left the store and left his employee Jony in charge. Two of his neighbors, Tom and Jane, bought a sack of sugar together and spent \$50, each of them paying \$25.

Unfortunately, Jony sold the sack to them without knowing that they are his boss's neighbors.

When Jack came back to the store, he saw that Jony made a mistake, so he sent him to pay Tom and Jane a \$5 discount.

Jony stole \$2 from the 5\$ and gave \$1.50 each to Tom and Jane, giving them a total of \$3. So now Tom and Jane have paid \$25 - \$1.50 = \$23.50.

Each one paid 23.50\$, so both Tom and Jane paid \$23.50 + \$23.50 = \$47 together.

Jony stole \$2, so the total is \$47 + \$2 = \$49

**Where is the missing \$1?**

Comment: If he takes \$3, there is \$1 extra. :p

Answer (score 4):

The trick to this puzzle is

> that it gets you to add when you should really subtract.

The last line: "So total is \$47+\$2=\$49" should be

> \$47-\$2=\$45 because the final cost is now $45

Answer (score 0):

He took the money from the customers, not from the store.

Once Jack returns to the store, the final cost of the item is \$50-\$5=\$45. Let's break it down into a series of actions.

\$50 - \$5
\$25 + \$25 - \$5
\$25 + \$25 - \$2 - \$1.50 - \$1.50
\$25 - \$1.50 + \$25 - \$1.50 - \$2
\$23.50 + \$23.50 - \$2
\$47 - \$2

Your final statement has reversed this subtraction into an addition.

Answer (score 0):

This puzzle is for Accountants.
Accounts were made wrong.

Correct:-
\$50 he received, so +50

\$5 he gave, so -5(3 discount given \& 2 stolen by employee)

So ultimately storekeeper has \$45 remains.

\$5 Debit , \$45 Credit=totals \$50

Answer (score 0):

Seeing it from another way is...

> Jack would have benefit of \$2 when he could sold it for \$47 instead of \$45
>
> Your final addition \$23.50 + \$23.50 = \$47 tells same thing that **seller** is benefited from **consumer** by \$2 but now Jony is the person who stole that part.